# Import contents of Text file into a List in Python

Tags: python, text, import

This is Regarding the projecteuler problem 42.
I want to import the content of this text file (https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p042_words.txt) in to a list  in python.

I want the list to be like 
list = ["A","ABILITY",........]
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are several answers that already cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code:

```
mylist=[]
with open('p042_words.txt','r') as f:
    mylist=f.readlines()
l=[]
for i in mylist:
    l=l+i.split(',')
print(l)
```

if you want remove '"' character from each word use following code:

```
import re
mylist=[]
with open('p042_words.txt','r') as f:
    mylist=f.readlines()

l=[]
for i in mylist:
    j=re.sub('["]','',i)
    l=l+j.strip('"').split(',')
print(l)
```

Comment: The List will looks like this ['"A","ABILITY","ABLE","ABOUT","ABOVE","ABSENCE","ABSOLUTELY...] there is only one word in the list beacause the whole text in txt file i covered with ' ' .

Comment: @ChandraIrugalbandara I edit my answer again please check again

Answer (score 0):

The values in the file are comma separated so you can use the csv reader. It will take care of everything for you.

```
import csv

with open('p042_words.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lst = [item for item in csv.reader(infile)][0]
```

the `[0]` is because there is only one line in the CSV file.

lst will now contain:

```
['A', 'ABILITY', 'ABLE', 'ABOUT', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to split the words once you load them, then strip the quotation marks from them to get the desired result, i.e.

```
with open("p042_words.txt", "r") as f:
    words = [word.strip("\"' \t\n\r") for word in f.read().split(",")]

print(words)
# ['A', 'ABILITY', 'ABLE', 'ABOUT', 'ABOVE', ...]
```

Technically, for this file simple stripping of quotation marks should be enough, but I've added the common whitespace and single quotation marks just in case.